# Removing a list of characters from a view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

One of my fields in showing  the file names in a folder.
I only need to show the name of the file but it is also showing the extension.

Currently it is showing like Theme1.html
but I want it to show Theme only
I tried to remove the last characters using

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ThemeName.Remove(item.ThemeName.Length-5))
```

but it is throwing error

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ThemeName.Substring(0,item.ThemeName.LastIndexOf('.'))`

Comment: You should do the string manipulation before you expose the property to your view. Then you could add a unit test to verify that code that removes the file ending works correct. For the actual string manipulation code, see anands answer

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Thank you for the suggestion. I made the manipulation in the controller before passing the list to the View and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to make the changes in the string in controller and then pass the list to the view. 
So I used the below code in the controller .

```
templates[i].ThemeName = templates[i].ThemeName.Substring(0, templates[i].ThemeName.Length - 5);
```

Comment: Why did you accept the answer you did? - its WRONG!

Comment: @StephenMuecke It helped,It was not the exact answer but I used the same logic in controller instead of the View. **Here is the code ** templates[i].ThemeName = templates[i].ThemeName.Substring(0, templates[i].ThemeName.Length - 5);

Comment: Fine, But remove your acceptance of Akshay's answer - an accepted answer indicates to others that it works (and it does not!). And you should edit your answer to show what worked for you and accept it.

Comment: And remove the _I guess all you guys have given correct answer_ in your answer - None of the other answers are correct!

Comment: @StephenMuecke   This one is also working      templates[i].ThemeName = templates[i].ThemeName.Substring(0, templates[i].ThemeName.LastIndexOf('.'));

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi I have answered the question and marked it as answer can you please remove the negative vote, I am unable to post questions and I need it urgently.

Comment: I have not voted on the question or any of the answers!! Do you want me to now? (and voting is anonymous so never accuse another user). And by the way, you should be using the [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am sorry, It was not my intention to accuse you of anything, I just thought if you have voted negative then you can take it back as I have done what you wanted as I need to ask some quetons very urgently which I am unable to post, I didn't mean to accuse you.

Comment: Only 2 of your questions have been negative scores, so you cannot be banned from asking questions because of that.

Answer (score 2):

> > Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

The helper takes **expression**, not the function. Then it processes the expression. As the message says, it can't process function calls inside of expressions. You have to provide model with calculated values, but not calculate the value inside of expression.

> I only need to show the name of the file but it is also showing the extension.

Use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove an `int` with your code. I think you were trying to use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ThemeName.Remove(item.Substring(item.ThemeName.Length-5)))
```

A better way to do it is to use `LastIndexOf`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ThemeName.Substring(0,item.ThemeName.LastIndexOf('.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `split` method

```
  string fileName= "abc.123.txt";
  int fileExtPos = fileName.LastIndexOf(".");
  if (fileExtPos >= 0 ){
     fileName= fileName.Substring(0, fileExtPos);
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this fails when you have ' . ' in file name

Comment: i have separated the value by `'.'` only how it fails

Comment: if your filename abx.xyz.pfd what will be the output from your solution?

Comment: yep the answer will be abx

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ThemeName.Substring(0,item.ThemeName.Length-5))
```

Try Substring instead of Remove

Comment: why then is this the answer? lol Did it actually help? just for everyone else to know.

Comment: @MiquelColl Yes it helped.It was not the exact answer but I used the same logic in controller instead of the View. **Here is the code **                                      templates[i].ThemeName = templates[i].ThemeName.Substring(0, templates[i].ThemeName.Length - 5);

Comment: @MiquelColl Hi I have answered the question and marked it as answer can you please remove the negative vote, I am unable to post questions and I need it urgently.

Comment: hi @simba I did not vote with a negative vote so I can't undo it :( Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it might be work for you

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ThemeName.Splite(".")[0])
```